# How to add new column to existing table in Magento programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, install-script

How can I add a new column to existing Magento core table via install script? (without using pure SQL)

I want to use the Magento way which is using alias methods to create install script.

So far I followed few tutorials. But seems to be not working properly. This StackOverflow [ALTER TABLE in Magento setup script without using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315660/alter-table-in-magento-setup-script-without-using-sql) answer was somewhat similar to my question. But what is the content should be put into module's `confg.xml` file? Do I need to just define resource model, model and setup data would be enough?

The relevant portion of the `config.xml` (of my module) is as follow.

```
<config>
 . . . 
<global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_resource</resourceModel>
            </mymodule>
            <mymodule_resource>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource</class>
            </mymodule_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_setup>
            <mymodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_read>
            <mymodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_write>
        </resources>
. . . .
</config>
```

And my install script is as follows.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_flat_order'),'custom_value', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
), 'Title');
$installer->endSetup();
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '255.sales_flat_order' doesn't exist

Any suggestion to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the databasename `255`?

Comment: no. database name is something else.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`sales_flat_order` is the full name of the `table` and so you have to use alias in `$installer->getTable()`

In `$installer->getTable()` parameter like `module_alias/table_alias.`

In that case try with

```
$installer->getTable('sales/order')
```

When you write this it will return table name `sales_flat_order`

because

```
module_alias = sales

table_alias = order
```

---

***EDIT***

You can use below script to add new column. It works fine in my system

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'),'custom_value', array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'length'    => 255,
    'after'     => null, // column name to insert new column after
    'comment'   => 'Title'
    ));   
$installer->endSetup();
```

I am using `Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT` insted of `Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR` because `TYPE_VARCHAR` is deprecated

You can check @ `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::$_ddlColumnTypes`

And If you specify type `TYPE_TEXT` but set length to lets say `255` Magento will create a `MySQL` column of `VARCHAR` type.

Comment: tried this, Even though I'm getting the same response

Comment: @Sukeshini check my edit....

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly and +1 for the effort you made to solve my issue.

Comment: glad to hear that it works for you @Sukeshini

Comment: @KeyurShah how to add a new field into custom table ?

Answer (score 5):

You are misusing the method `addColumn`:

```
public function addColumn($tableName, $columnName, $definition, $schemaName = null)
```

the fourth parameter is the schemaName, in your call, the fourth parameter is `255`.

```
->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_flat_order'),'custom_value', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 255, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
), 'Title')
```

If you use the right parameters, it should work.

Comment: TYPE_VARCHAR is deprecated so we have to use TYPE_TEXT as per Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::$_ddlColumnTypes .,,correct me if i am wrong. @Fabian

Comment: You are right. TYPE_TEXT with a length < 255 maxes automatically a varchar.

Comment: @Fabian Blechschmidt: Thanks for pointing out the missed places. and +1

Answer (score 4):

*I realize this is a relatively 'old' question, but as it's still pretty find-able by Google, I decided to add this bit of information.*

Regarding your question, if you want to change the sales/order table, this should not be done by the traditional install scripts/setup. The `Mage_Catalog` module uses a different `Resource_Setup` class, namely `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup`.

If you want to add attributes to the sales/order model, in order to ensure everything is added and processed correctly, add your attribute like this:

```
<?php

// Start setup
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup $installer */
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

// Gather info
$entityType = 'order'; // Adding attribute to this entity type (must be written out in text, not the entity type ID!! That'll not work.
$attributeName = 'my_attribute_code'; // Your attribute code/name

// Add attribute, very few parameters are accepted.
$installer->addAttribute($entityType, $attributeName, array(
    'type'              => 'varchar'
));

// End setup
$installer->endSetup();
```

Should you wonder *why*, then the answer is within the `addAttribute()` function of the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup` class:

```
/**
 * Add entity attribute. Overwrited for flat entities support
 *
 * @param int|string $entityTypeId
 * @param string $code
 * @param array $attr
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
 */
public function addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)
{
    if (isset($this->_flatEntityTables[$entityTypeId]) &&
        $this->_flatTableExist($this->_flatEntityTables[$entityTypeId]))
    {
        $this->_addFlatAttribute($this->_flatEntityTables[$entityTypeId], $code, $attr);
        $this->_addGridAttribute($this->_flatEntityTables[$entityTypeId], $code, $attr, $entityTypeId);
    } else {
        parent::addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, $attr);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Good Catch.. Never know we can use `addAttribute` for Sales_Order module

Comment: This is actually the most correct answer.

Comment: I was using `$this` installer, your answer pointed me to the right direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

simply you can create a script and in you dbscripts folder and run this file from terminal or web browser.

e.g save file in `/dbscripts/filename.php` paste this code and change according to your requirement

```
 <?php

require_once '../app/Mage.php';
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//umask(0);

Mage::app();

/** @var Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup $installer */

/*mysql4-install-0.1.0.php*/
$installer = new Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();
//echo $installer->getTable('maxoptra/maxoptratable');
//die("here");
$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE `Table_name` ADD `New_Column_name` TEXT NOT NULL AFTER `other_exiting_column_name`");

$installer->endSetup();

echo"Script Run Successfully";
```

run this file from browser like

```
domain.name/dbscripts/filename.php
```